# Exception in the case of Overriding

Tags: java

As we know that in the case if method overriding If child class method throws some checked exception then compulsory parent class method should throw same checked exception or its parent class exception otherwise we will get compile error. But there is no rule on un-checked exception.

But if assume that Java allows parent class method to have checked exception which is child to the child class method checked exception.

Can some one please why this is not allowed in the Java.

---

Let put the question in a different way :

you have class A -

```
class A {

    public void doStuff() throws SQLException {

    }
}
```

and class B extends A -

```
class B extends A {

    public void doStuff() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

It will throw exception during compilation because of violation of the method's contract.

Assume that the Java would allows this then what would be the consequences ?

Comment: Explain why *what* is not allowed?  Can you add some code to illustrate?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I think his problem is that an overriden method cannot have a `throws` clause if the parent method doesn't throw the same (or a more general) exception.

Comment: @Tom Yes, because checked exceptions are part of the class' contract and, according to Liskov's Substitution Principle, subclasses must adhere to the contract. Other than that, I don't understand a single word from the second part of the OP's question.

Comment: @Powerslave me neither :D.

Comment: I believe the question is: "Why can't an overriding method throw a more general exception than the overridden method?" I.e. the exception thrown by the overridden method extends the exception thrown by the overriding method. This is also how Boris seems to have interpreted it.

Comment: @Lonenebula Ah, that's simple. The case with LSP holds true here. Also, like with any other type, one cannot assign the value of a more general type to a variable of a specific type. It's just like one cannot compile `Child o = new Parent()`. When the client code catches the exception, it is implicitly assigned to - usually - `e`. Thanks for pointing things out!

Answer (score 8):

I suppose you are asking why I cannot do this:

```
class Parent {
    void doStuff() throws FileNotFoundException {

    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    void doStuff() throws IOException {

    }
}
```

This is simple, what happens when I do:

```
final Parent parent = new Child();

try {
    parent.doStuff();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the `Child` decides to throw a, say [`SocketException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html)?

I, correctly, try and `catch FileNotFoundException` from the call `parent.doStuff` but this will not catch the `SocketException`.

How I have an uncaught *checked* exception. This is not allowed.

If I specifically try and `catch SocketException` this will result in a compiler error as `SocketException` is not declared as thrown from `Parent.doStuff`.

The only way to solve this in the general case would be to always `catch Exception` as any child class can declare that it throws a more general type and bypass my `catch`.  This is obviously not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The `throws` clause is part of the signature of a method, and in order to override a method, the overriding method must have the same signature as the overriden method.

Therefore, if class `B` extends class `A` and `A` defines :

```
public void foo (int param) throws SomeException
{
    ....
    if (something)
        throw new SomeException ();
    ....
}
```

Then `B` can only override foo by using the same signature :

```
public void foo (int param) throws SomeException
{
    super.foo(param);
    ....
    if (something)
        throw new SomeOtherException ();
    ....
}
```

`SomeOtherException` must be a sub-class of `SomeException`, since that's the type of exception the method signature allows to throw. If the overriding method would attempt to throw an exception of a type which is a super class of `SomeException`, it would violate the method's contract.

Let's declare some class hierarchy of exception classes :

```
SuperException
    SomeException
        SomeOtherException
    AnotherSomeException
```

What you propose (`Java allows parent class method to have checked exception which is child to the child class method checked exception`) would allow the overriding method in the child class to throw any exceptions of type `SuperException`, which would allow it to throw `AnotherSomeException`. This violates the method's signature, since `AnotherSomeException` is not a sub-class of `SomeException`.

To expand on my comment, lets consider what would happen if Java allowed what you propose.

Suppose class `C` has a method `bar` that accepts an instance of class `A` and calls the method `foo`.

```
public class C
{
    ....
    public void bar (A a)
    {
        try {
            a.foo ();
        }
        catch (SomeException ex) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Since `foo` is declared to throw `SomeException`, any code that calls `foo` must handle this exception or declare that it may throw this exception. Now, if Java would allow `B` to override `foo`, but change its declaration to `public void foo() throws Exception`, the implementation of `foo` in `B` may throw any sub-class of `Exception`. Since `bar` doesn't even know that `B` exists, it doesn't know it has to catch any exception other than `SomeException` and its sub-classes. Therefore the compiler can't mark this code as an error, but if the caller of `bar` would pass to it an instance of `B`, the code would become invalid only in runtime, since it may throw a checked excpetion that is neither caught nor declared by `bar`. That's why Java doesn't allow you to change the `throws` clause when you override a method.

Comment: Thanks for understanding !

Let put the question in a different way :

you have class A -

class A {

public void doStuff() throws SQLException {

}
}

and class B extends A -

class B extends A {

public void doStuff() throws Exception {

}
}

It will throw exception during compilation because of violation of the method's contract.

Assume that the Java would allows this then what would be the consequences ?

Comment: @Anish the consequence of allowing this would be that any code that calls the doStuff method would catch SQLException,  but if it would call the method on an instance of B, it would have an error that the compiler can't detect , since the code that uses doStuff of class A may not know anything about class B.

Comment: As you told-Then B can only override foo by using the same signature :please conside the case of uncheked exception where you can use diffent signeture as well.
For ex-
Parent-public void foo (int param) {}
Child-public void foo (int param) throws NullPointerException

Comment: also there are many scenario where parent and child have different signature of exception declaretion in case of overriding.

Answer (score 1):

An overriding method can not throw a checked exception if it is not specified in the parent class. The reason is, that you want to be able to use an instance of the subtype wherever you can pass the supertype, i.e., your subtype needs to **behave** the same way your supertype does. However, if your subtype can throw an exception, then it does not behave the same way: it can throw an exception. The same is true for unchecked exceptions, but, as the name already tells us, they are not checked by the compiler, so this is just not inforced statically.

I suggest you have a look at the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

**Example on why it would be bad for a subclass to throw an Exception where the superclass does promise to not throw an exception:**

```
class Animal {
  void eatMeat() {System.out.println("eating meat");}
}

class Zebra extends Animal {
  void eatMeat() throws IsVegetarianException {throw new IsVegetarianException(); }
}
```

Well... maybe your `Zebra` isn't an animal, or the interface of `Animal` is too broad. Maybe not all `Animal`s eat meat. By the way: This happened in various Java collection interfaces. They solve this by throwing the unchecked `NotSupportedException`, but it is just a flaw in the design, for which there exists no good solution other than changing the design.

Answer (score 1):

I may not be correct, but I think you are asking why superclass A cannot extend subclass B who extends class A.

This cannot exist because there is lack of clarity over which is the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

If you override a method with no throw declaration, you can throw a `RuntimeException` or a subclass without declaration.

```
class A {
    public void run() {

    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new RuntimeException("throw without declaration");
    }
}
```

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html):

> `RuntimeException` and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions.
>   Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or
>   constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of
>   the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or
>   constructor boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Because `throws SQLException` really means "throw **only** `SQLException`" or in other words don't throw anything except `SQLException`

So, if you throw something else you'll broke that contract. On the other hand you can make it other way around

```
class A {

    public void doStuff() throws Exception  {

    }
}

class B extends A {

    public void doStuff() throws SQLException {

    }
}
```

because you just make more strict contract that way.